# Regex to strip anything that isn't an html comment

Tags: php, regex

I know using a regex to parse html is normally a non-starter but I don't want anything that clever...

Taking this example

```
<div><!--<b>Test</b>-->Test</div>
<div><!--<b>Test2</b>-->Test2</div>
```

I'd like to strip out ANYTHING that isn't between `<!--` and `-->` to get:

```
<b>Test</b><b>Test2</b>
```

Tags are guaranteed to be correctly matched (no unclosed/nested comments).

What regex do I need to use?

Comment: [You shouldn't try to parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @Bohemian I've read it - Hence my first sentence, but I'm dealing with a very specific circumstance - find all text which has a `<!--` in front of it and `-->` after it. It's not really parsing at all but string matching. If the question had been "Find everything enclosed in brackets", nobody would bat an eyelid...

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/eYvaJj

Comment: @Gordon - a nice alternative. I gave it a try and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the pattern:

```
(?s)((?!-->).)*<!--|-->((?!<!--).)*
```

with an empty string.

A short explanation:

```
(?s)              # enable DOT-ALL
((?!-->).)*<!--   # match anything except '-->' ending with '<!--'
|                 # OR
-->((?!<!--).)*   # match '-->' followed by anything except '<!--'
```

Be careful when processing (X)HTML with regex. Whenever parts of comments occur in tag-attributes or CDATA blocks, things go wrong.

### EDIT

Seeing your most active tag is JavaScript, here's a JS demo:

```js
print(
  "<div><!--<b>Test</b>-->Test</div>\n<div><!--<b>Test2</b>-->Test2</div>"
  .replace(
    /((?!-->)[\s\S])*<!--|-->((?!<!--)[\s\S])*/g,
    ""
  )
);
```

which prints:

```
<b>Test</b><b>Test2</b>
```

Note that since JS does not support the `(?s)` flag, I used the equivalent `[\s\S]` which matches any character (including line break chars).

Test it on Ideone here: http://ideone.com/6yQaK

### EDIT II

And a PHP demo would look like:

```php
<?php
$s = "<div><!--<b>Test</b>-->Test</div>\n<div><!--<b>Test2</b>-->Test2</div>";
echo preg_replace('/(?s)((?!-->).)*<!--|-->((?!<!--).)*/', '', $s);
?>
```

which also prints:

```
<b>Test</b><b>Test2</b>
```

as can be seen on Ideone: http://ideone.com/Bm2uJ

Comment: @Basiclife, you're welcome. Also see the EDIT with a small demo.

Comment: Nicely spotted on the tags but this is actually for use in PHP - `preg_replace("/(?s)((?!-->).)*<!--|-->((?!<!--).)*
/i", "", $Source);` seems to result in a "The server unexpectedly closed the cnnection` and no errors in the PHP logs. Not sure why - would you mind proiding a PHP example? Many thanks

Comment: @Basiclife, sure, see EDIT II for a PHP demo.

Comment: Thanks Bart, that worked - not sure why mine didn't but I'll spend some time digging when I can

Answer (score 1):

```
s/-->.*?<--//g strips off anything between "-->" and the next "<--"

s/^.*?<--// strips off from the beginning to the first occurence of "<--"

s/-->.*?$// strips off from the last occurence of "-->" to the end
```

`.*` matches any amount of characters and `.*?` matches the least possible amount of characters, so that the hole pattern matches

`^` stands for the beginning of a string and $ for the end

Comment: Yes please - an explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be this

```
.*?<!--(.*?)-->.*?(?=<!--|$)
```

and replace with

```
$1
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vnvg)

If you read your string row by row, this would match anything till the first comment, put the content of the first content into group 1 and then match anything till the end of the row or the next comment.